# Does mpmath support very small numbers? (Python)

Tags: python, numbers, mpmath

I'm trying to solve a numerical maths problem, and for that I need python to handle very small numbers. For that, I installed mpmath.
It doesn't quite work as desired though.
Mpmath is able to handle 1e-300 but not 1e-400 (10^-300 but not 10^-400 respectively)

In the head I have

```
from mpmath import mp
from mpmath import mpf

mp.dps = 500
```

If I type

```
x = mpf(1e-300)
print(x)
```

I get a thousand digit number, that is close to 1e-300 (which is what I want)

However, if I now type

```
y = mpf(1e-400)
print(y)
```

I get the result: `0.0`, which is not what I want.

I tried to ramp up the decimal precision (e.g. mp.dps = 3000) but it didn't help, I still got zero in the second case.

Is there a way to circumvent this, or is mpmath just unable to do handle 1e-400?

Comment: python interprets the literal while it's lexing the document, and because 1e-400 isn't possible with regular python types, it is converted to 0.0 before being passed to the function

Answer (score 4):

Issue is you're running into the accuracy of [double floating point numbers](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/technical.html)

- Doubles have a range of 1e-300 to 1e+300.
- Provide the number to mpmath as a string so it converts it rather than passing a float

Meaning change from:

```
y = mpmath(1e-400) # 1e-400 becomes 0 as a 
                   # float due to limited
                   # doubles accuracy
```

To:

```
y = mpmath('1e-400')
```

**Test**

```
from mpmath import mp
from mpmath import mpf

mp.dps = 500 

y = mpf('1e-400')
for k in range(10):
  print(k*y)
```

*Output*

```
1.0e-400
2.0e-400
3.0e-400
4.0e-400
5.0e-400
6.0e-400
7.0e-400
8.0e-400
9.0e-400
```